# Binding JSON information to data-groups in ionic app

Tags: json, html, angular, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic app with the latest version (Ionic 3xx and Angular 5) and trying to integrate shuffleJS feature into it for filtering. It worked ok when I used some static data in my template via the 'data-groups' HTML5 attr.

However, when I try to have each item's 'data-groups' be populated by a JSON feed, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'data-groups' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Here is the HTML template code:

```
        <ion-grid id="container">
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-2 *ngFor="let macro of allMacros" (click)="goToMacroDetailsPage(macro)" class="item">
              <div class="item" [data-groups]="macro.cssClasses"></div>
              <ion-card>
                <img src="../assets/imgs/specimens/thumbs/{{macro.thumbnail}}.jpg"/>
                <ion-card-content>
                  <ion-card-title>
                    {{macro.title}}
                  </ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-content>
              </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

..and an example of the JSON data feed:

```
   },
    {
      "title": "Caddisfly",
      "cssClasses": "nonmicro noshell threepairs notail verySens",
      "thumbnail": "caddisfly-th",
      "featured_image": [
        "caddisfly/caddisfly1",
        "caddisfly/caddisfly2",
        "caddisfly/caddisfly3"
      ],
      "sensitivity": "Tolerant",
      "phylum": "Anthropoda",
      "class": "Insecta",
      "order": "Trichoptera",
      "family": "Twenty-six families",
      "size": "1.5 &ndash; 40mm",
      "habitat": "In sediment, on rocks and branches, and among algae and aquatic plants in streams, ponds and lakes",
      "diet": "<strong>Carnivorous, herbivorous</strong> or <strong>detritivorous</strong> depending on species &ndash; algae scraped from the surface or surrounding rocks; material filtered from currents using specially constructed conical webs; insects and <strong>crustaceans</strong>",
      "features": "Two main types, divided on the basis of behaviour and structure. One group constructs a portable case out of sand, algae, plant material and <strong>silt</strong> (cases often look like sticks) and are generally found in still  waters where they feed on algae and plants. The second group does not have a case, or has a fixed retreat. Some are common in fast-flowing water where they feed on other animals (often building a net of silk across the stream to capture their food). Some <strong>species</strong> will swim in their case; most just crawl around. Some of the caseless will move away backwards"
    },
```

I thought 'data-groups' would have been a supported data attribute according to HTML5 standards - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong if it is something Angular specific that I must do (i.e. import a module).

Comment: [tag:angular] !== [tag:angularjs]

Comment: that being said, `data-*` attributes are custom;  they are not **defined as properties** of the element, but they are allowed to exist.  You can use interpolation to set their values, but you cannot *bind* to them. (i.e. you can do `data-groups="{{macro.cssClasses}}"`)

Comment: Funny that you say that. I did try and previously use the method that you described there @Claies but I got a similar error of 'compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'groups' since it isn't a known property of 'div''

Comment: Inerestingly, when I don't try to use binding/interpolation and just manually put in a string value (i.e. data-groups='["animals"]') - this did not cause any errors/failures.

Comment: Ohhh... @Claies, I finally understand your first statement. Yes I am using Angular AND NOT AngularJS (which is Angular v1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your groups like following and it should work

[attr.data-groups]="macro.cssClasses"

I think there are few problems in your code apart from this binding issue:

- data-groups in shuffjs accepts array of strings but its a string in your appData.json file under cssClasses key.
- in filter.html use ../../assets/imgs/specimens/thumbs/{{macro.thumbnail}}.jpg
  instead of ../assets/imgs/specimens/thumbs/{{macro.thumbnail}}.jpg to display  your thumbnails

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, now working alot better. Yes you are right, my code needs to be cleaned up more and I need to split the cssClasses string into a separate array for it to be used properly.

Comment: glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-attr-groups = “{{macro.cssClasses}}”
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes
Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I am getting the same error message. :(

Comment: Can give fiddle or something?